# Fullcalendar: pass events as a C# string

Tags: c#, json, string, fullcalendar

I have the following question about fullcalendar plugin: is it possible to pass the events as a string variable? I apologize, I am new to this thing, I have tried json and xml but could not make those work (yeah that's me being loser) and I decided to try ugly but what-if-it-works way. However, it does not work either and I would like to ask if it is even possible.

Can anyone please explain me how to handle the situation when I need to extract data from database, parse it as json and feed to fullcalendar as events (in my code: machines)? I have read the data from database and put it into list, can serialize it as json too, but how to feed it to events? What function is needed?

My code is here:

There is nothing related to calendar in aspx file, but in code behind:

```
public string WorstCodeEverMakeEvent(string ttl, DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate, string starttime)
            { //this function make string of one event
                string datestart = "new Date(" + startdate.Year + ", " +
            startdate.Month + ", " + startdate.Day + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(starttime).Hour + ", " +
            Convert.ToDateTime(starttime).Minute + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(starttime).Second + ")";
        string ohnowhy = "{title: " + ttl + ", start: " + datestart + "}";
        return ohnowhy;
    }
    protected void btnCheckTimetable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               // date, machine_id, time, length, suborder_id, order_id
         List<Tuple<string,int,string,int,int,int>> machines = new List<Tuple<string,int,string,int,int,int>>();
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(22);
        for (DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2); dt <= endDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
        {
            SqlCommand getMachineTimes = new SqlCommand
               (@"SELECT TimeStart, Length, SubOrderID, OrderID
                   FROM MachineDates 
                    WHERE MachineID=@mid AND [Date]=@dt", con);
            getMachineTimes.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mid", lbxMachines.SelectedValue);
            getMachineTimes.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt.ToShortDateString());
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                con.Open();
            reader = getMachineTimes.ExecuteReader(); // this is to get data    about machines from database
    // machines = events
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                    machines.Add(new Tuple<string, int, string, int, int, int>
                        (dt.ToShortDateString(), int.Parse(lbxMachines.SelectedValue),
                        reader[0].ToString(), int.Parse(reader[1].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader[2].ToString()), int.Parse(reader[3].ToString())));
                else
                    machines.Add(new Tuple<string, int, string, int, int, int>
                        (dt.ToShortDateString(), int.Parse(lbxMachines.SelectedValue),
                        null, 0, 0, 0));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        if (machines.Count != 0) //&& users.Count != 0
        {
            string allevents = "events:[";
            foreach (Tuple<string, int, string, int, int, int> tup in machines)
            {
                allevents += WorstCodeEverMakeEvent
                    (tup.Item2.ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(tup.Item1),
                    Convert.ToDateTime(tup.Item1).AddHours(tup.Item4), tup.Item3);
            }

             ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script",
    @"<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () // page is now ready, initialize the   calendar...
    {
     var calendar;
    calendar = $('#calendarMain').fullCalendar(
        {
            weekMode:'#liquid',
            weekends: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            weekNumbers: true,
              theme: true,"
            + allevents+@"],
            //eventLimit: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            //defaultDate: new Date(y, m, d, 9, 00),
            editable: true,
            //defaultView: 'agendaMonth',
        });
})
    </script>", false);

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like making it more complicated is not the best way to solve the problem. But the only thing I see wrong is this:

```
string ohnowhy = "{title: " + ttl + ", start: " + datestart + "}";
```

Should be this:

```
string ohnowhy = "{title: \"" + ttl + "\", start: " + datestart + "}";
```

Edit: Also I'm not sure about your date. You might double check [the documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), but I've always passed in dates in this format: '2014-05-01'

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work :( But thank you anyway!